# PropertyInjection with open generic type using unity container throws exception

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I am trying to resolve a open generic type using unity container.  I am getting ResolutionFailed Exception. I am registering programmatically. Not able to understand what's going wrong in the InitContainer method.

Update: new InjectionProperty("Age",25)) in InitContainer  causing the exception.

Code using Unity 3.0

```
public abstract class Person<T> where T : class
{
    protected T profession;
    public Person(T profession)
    {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
    public abstract void WhoAreYou();
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Employee<T> : Person<T> where T : class
{
    string personType;
    public Employee(T profession, string personType) : base(profession)
    {
        this.personType = personType;
    }

    public override void WhoAreYou()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am " + personType);
        Console.WriteLine("My age is " + Age);           
        Console.WriteLine("Profession" + typeof(T).ToString());           
    }
}
public abstract class Profession { }
public class Doctor : Profession { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = InitContainer();           
        var p = container.Resolve<Person<Doctor>>();
        p.WhoAreYou();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static UnityContainer InitContainer()
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType(typeof(Person<>), typeof(Employee<>),
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() , 
            new InjectionConstructor(new GenericParameter("T"),  "Employee"), 
            new InjectionProperty("Age",25));
        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... what is the benefit of going this route? I just see a mountain of problems just waiting to happen, at this point...

Comment: Just I am practicing the container to understand the existing code.

Comment: You are trying to resolve a Employee<Doctor>  but the constructor needs `personType`

Comment: The Employee constructor requires two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you actually found a bug in Unity!

This issue only occurs when you attempt to use the combination of an `InjectionProperty` on an inherited property with an open generics registration.  This *should* be a supported scenario.  I was able to reproduce this issue on Unity 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0 (latest).

Any of the following fixes the issue...

- Remove generics
- Change to closed generics registration
- Move the property to the concrete class
- Make the property abstract or virtual on the base class
- Set the property in a different way other than using an `InjectionProperty`